# discord.js : how do I pick up a random item from a json file?

Tags: json, random, discord.js

I'm coding a discord bot. I want to it to pick up in a json file a random item from a list. That's my json file :

```
{
    "emailPass": ["email1:pass1", "email2:pass2"],
    "capture": "capture1"
}
```

Now I want it to send a private message to the author, with the "capture" item, and one of the "emailPass" items, randomly chosen. So that's my js code :

```
message.author.send(Math.floor(jsonFile.emailPass.lenght*Math.random()) + "\n" + jsonFile.capture);
```

The bot sends the message, but instead of the "emailPass" item, it displays "NaN".
Does someone know how to fix that ? I think the error is from the random command, but I don't know exactly why...

Answer (score 0):

Use Math.floor(jsonFile["emailPass"].length * Math.random()).
But this will only output a random number between 0 and the number of values in your emailPass array - 1. Use this if you want to return a random element from there:

```
message.author.send(jsonFile.emailPass[Math.floor(jsonFile["emailPass"].length * Math.random())] + "\n" + jsonFile.capture);
```

Comment: Nice to hear it ^^